# send xml as message in a xml

Tags: android, xml, web-services, ksoap2

I need to send 3 things from my app to a web service: username + password and a message which contains more XML.

```
request.addProperty("username", username);
request.addProperty("password", password);
request.addProperty("message", UitVoer); // uitvoer is a String that contains XML
```

I use the ksoap2 librabry which always worked great for android <-> web service, but atm I'm not sure if it still works for what I need.

When I check my `envelope.bodyOut`, all tags and < > signs look like they should.
But then I get an error message from the web service with the XML I sent, and it shows the HTML code for those signs.

Does ksoap2 replace the signs and should I use another way to send my stuff to the web service, or is there something wrong on the web service side? 
(I have no control over the web service so I have no clue what it does on that side.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you build an xml request; hope this helps:)

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();  
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();  
Element rootElement = document.createElement("map");  
document.appendChild(rootElement);  

Element em = document.createElement("string");  
em.setAttribute("name", "FirstName");  
em.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Rita"));  
rootElement.appendChild(em);  

em = document.createElement("string");  
em.setAttribute("name", "LastName");  
em.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Roy"));  
rootElement.appendChild(em);  


TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            Properties outFormat = new Properties();
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperties(outFormat);
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement());
            OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            strXMLInput = output.toString();
```

Comment: it turned out the 1 that made the xml had miss placed an endtag which the webservice didnt accept (duh).

after removing the endtag it worked, so won't use this answer but as it might help against missplacing the endtag i will make this the correct answer.

(for the html code in places of the < > tags, the webservice did it when sending the error back)

Comment: That Sounds good :) It has more than one way of doing it ;) Just needs to be suitable for us :)